# Under what legislation has former U.S. President Trump been indicted for "conspiracy to defraud the US"?

Tags: united-states, criminal-law, indictment

It's reported by [BBC News](https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/live/world-us-canada-66248859) that Mr Trump is charged with four counts, including:

- conspiracy to defraud the US
- tampering with a witness
- conspiracy against the rights of citizens

Focusing on the first bullet point to avoid asking multiple questions<sup>1</sup>:

**What legislation introduces and/or covers the offence of defrauding the US?**

---

<sub><sup>1</sup>Although I would be interested in knowing more on the underlying legislation for a charge of conspiracy against the rights of citizens which I might post as a follow-up question</sub>

Comment: Comment on your aside about conspiracy against rights: That’s 18 U.S. Code s. 241.

Comment: Detailed analysis of the statutes implicated can be found at https://www.lawfaremedia.org/article/trump-jan.-6-indictment-the-statutes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Count 1: 18 U.S.C. § 371 (Conspiracy to Defraud United States)

Here the indictment's introduction alleges that Trump perpetrated:

> A conspiracy to to defraud the United States by using dishonesty,
> fraud, and deceit to impair, obstruct, and defeat the lawful federal
> government function by which the results of the presidential election
> are collected, counted, and certified by the federal government, in
> violation of 18 U.S.C. § 371.

temporary link to indictment pdf pending finding a better version: https://d3i6fh83elv35t.cloudfront.net/static/2023/08/trump-indictment.pdf

[18 U.S.C. § 371 (Cornell Law School Legal Information Institute)](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/18/371):

> If two or more persons conspire either to commit any offense against
> the United States, or to defraud the United States, or any agency
> thereof in any manner or for any purpose, and one or more of such
> persons do any act to effect the object of the conspiracy, each shall
> be fined under this title or imprisoned not more than five years, or
> both.
>
> If, however, the offense, the commission of which is the object of the
> conspiracy, is a misdemeanor only, the punishment for such conspiracy
> shall not exceed the maximum punishment provided for such misdemeanor.

Comment: 10b and 10c in this document look very bad for Trump to me. Concerning the "dead voters": The BBC checked the first 33 names on a list of "dead voters" and found every single one was alive, but someone else with the same name and close date of birth had died, mostly in different states. Plus one voter who lived with his dad, who had the same name. The dad died shortly before the election. Two papers inviting him to vote arrived at the house. The voter took _one_ of them and voted, but it seems he took the wrong paper by mistake. So the outcome was not affected by this mistake.